# No such property error for String in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

So I have the following bit of code (the important bits):

```
import java.lang.String;
//More imports ...

String errorString = ""
//More global variables

def mainMethod(){
    if (errorString.length()) {
        errorString += "BTW, fields with errors must be either corrected or set back to their original value before proceeding."
        invalidInputException = new InvalidInputException(errorString);
    }
}
```

Then when I run the script Jira throws back at me in `catalina.out` the following error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: errorString for class: com.onresolve.jira.groovy.canned.workflow.validators.editAssigneeValidation
```

So I am unsure on why the script is not recognizing errorString as a variable or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you are using this code as an script. Upon compilation, all code not contained in methods will be put in the `run()` method, thus, your `errorString` will be declared in the `run()` method, and your `mainMethod()` will try to work with an `errorString` which doesn't exist neither in its own scope nor in the class' scope.

Some solutions:

#### 1. [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html)

Adding `@Field` turns your `errorString` into a field in the compiled script class

```
@groovy.transform.Field String errorString = ""

def mainMethod(){
    if (errorString.length()) {
        errorString += "BTW, fields with errors must be either corrected or set back to their original value before proceeding."
        invalidInputException = [error: errorString]
    }
}

mainMethod()
```

#### 2. Binding

Remove the type declaration, so `errorString` will be contained in the script's binding:

```
errorString = ""

def mainMethod(){
    if (errorString.length()) {
        errorString += "BTW, fields with errors must be either corrected or set back to their original value before proceeding."
        invalidInputException = [error: errorString]
    }
}

mainMethod()
```

---

Here is groovyConsole output of your script:

[image: ast]

Comment: So using the `@Field` descriptor. Do I have to do that for every variable that I define, or just for `String`?

Comment: Only once to the script

Comment: Ah so just throw it like so:
`@Field \n var1 \n var2 \n etc...` ?

Comment: I don't quite get the reasoning entirely I think. We already have a Script class instance a binding object. What's the downside of just binding those 'class' variables to the instance instead of putting them into the run method only when they have a type or 'def' attached to them?

Comment: Binding option did not work for me. @Field worked. Just to add, Jenkins documentation only mentions first option. may be that is the reason. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `@Field` annotation to `errorString`:

```
import java.lang.String
import groovy.transform.Field
//More imports ...

@Field
String errorString = ""
//More global variables

def mainMethod(){
    if (errorString.length()) {
        errorString += "BTW, fields with errors must be either corrected or set back to their original value before proceeding."
        invalidInputException = new     InvalidInputException(errorString);
    }
}
```